# Proofing (fixing punctuation, spaces, uppercase letters) a bio page text with php

Tags: php

I need help in trimming the bio info users submit inside their profiles.
Sometimes there are proofing problems:
"This is the bio OF Mike, OF being uppercase with no reason!there is no space between question mark and the word there?also the question mar should have a space.also after the stop sign there should be upper case,and spaces between this commas,and,this,one"

Here is what I am thinking:

First I'd trim $bio var

```
$bio = trim($bio);
```

Then I'd add spaces after punctuation marks - pretty sure this is not correct because it replaces every punctuation type with a comma.

```
$bio = str_replace(array(",","!","?"),", ", $bio);
```

Then I'd turn all the letters to lowercase; which won't work becouse I need to keep the uppercase for the first letter of the first word of the sentences inside the $bio variables.

```
$bio = strtolower($bio);
```

And finally I'd upper case the first one; but I need a way to upper case each first letter of every word separated by ! ? - or stop sign, you know... except commas.

```
$bio = strtoupper($bio);
```

Hope you can help

Comment: leave my bi0 alone, i will format it how i want to.

Comment: true:), maybe fiddle with it just a lil

Comment: considering the spelling and grammar errors in your own question, you may not be the best person to try and fix the work of others.

Comment: deserved that:), though I'm not native in english and the site is in another language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to warn you that it looks hopeless.

Anyway, you can maybe do something with a series of regexps:

```
 // This replaces , . ! ? (if NOT followed by a space) with the same (\1),
 // followed by a space, followed by whatever followed it before (\2).
 // Note that . and ? are special characters for regexes, so we have to
 // escape them with a "\".
 $bio = preg_replace('#([,\.!\?])(\S)#ms', '\1 \2', $bio);

 // Then replace all extra spaces: any sequence of 2 or more spaces is
 // replaced by one space.
 $bio = preg_replace('# {2,}#ms', ' ', $bio);

 // Then ., !, and ? followed by lowercase should uppercase it
 // We take the full monty, ". m" and uppercase it all. Since the uppercase
 // of ". " remains ". ", we keep things simpler.
 $bio = preg_replace('#[\.!\?] [a-z])#ms', 'strtoupper("\1")', $bio);

 // Then replace ALL CAPS words with lowerspace equivalent.
 // Doesn't seem a really good idea though: "I am Mike, I worked with NASA"
 // and NASA becomes nasa?
 $bio = preg_replace('# ([A-Z][A-Z]+)#mse', 'strtolower(" \1")', $bio);
```

This way, your sentence becomes:

This is the bio of Mike, of being uppercase with no reason! There is no space between question mark and the word there? Also the question mar should have a space. Also after the stop sign there should be upper case, and spaces between this commas, and, this, one

Comment: Ty very much, I understand now how preg_replace works, much better. Btw, not being a programer, I find it very hard to ever begin understanding regexes like this #([,\.!\?])(\S)#ms

Comment: It's not really all that difficult. Regexes are usually included between two characters; the first character of the string dictates what this character will be. It's best to use an unused character. While / is traditional, for HTML (which uses /) I use # or | instead. Then [...] means "all characters in this list", \s means "spaces" (tabs, etc), "\S" means "NOT spaces". After the regex is closed, characters like m and s order the parser to work in a specific way (the PHP manual has detailed instructions). I'm really not a regexp man myself, I just gleaned a few useful things.